# How to update and output a database without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have data which is a name. And I am having an **input type=text** where the value is equals to the name, together with a **button type=submit**. So what i'm trying to do is that, i want to change and update the name in my database and also output the new name without reloading the page at once because I want to run a JS function (Not Alert but a Toast Notification) which is I cannot do. So to shorten, ( EDIT -> UPDATE -> SHOW = without reloading the page).

**EDIT::** I'm sorry I forgot to mention. I know jQuery and AJAX is the solution but I am having trouble understanding AJAX not unlike jQuery.

**profile.php (FORM CODE)**

```
<form action="profile.php" method="POST">    
      <input type="text" id="changename" name="changename" class="form-control" placeholder="New Name" required>
      <button id="btnchange" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**profile.php (PHP CODE)**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['changename'])) {
        require 'connect.php';

        $newname = $_POST['changename'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['temp_user'];

        $sql = "UPDATE login SET login_name='$newname' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            header('location: profile.php');
            // MY JS FUNCTION HERE //
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read about `AJAX` on Google or here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: AJAX is your answer. There's *lots* of guide and tutorials if you search. And please don't shout in your question titles. I edited it for you

Comment: If you are using button type="Submit" it will defenetly reload your page so use button type="button" and use ajax for the further operation

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention: I know this might get done by using jQuery and AJAX and I can understand jQuery but I am having trouble using AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to update and output a databse without reloading the page?** what u looking for is AJAX.
I know you have selected the answer, but there's an extra information that you need that might help you in the long run

The are some good ajax tutorials you can follow in the web

1. [Ajax Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
2. [What is Ajax ?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm)

And many more you can find on the web.

This is what u need to do, first your form method is `GET` and on your php script you are requesting an `$_POST` therefore this will generate an undifined notice error,`changename` : **notice : undifined variable changename** so the solution is to use one method in a single form if your form is `$_GET` you use `$variable = $_GET['fieldname']` if form method is `POST` on your server side use `$variable = $_POST['fieldname'];` not the way you did. So lets change your form method to `POST` Then this is what u should do.

**edit.php**

Update

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('form').on('submit',function(event){

            event.preventDefault();//prevent the form from reloading the page when submit

            var formData = $('form').serialize(); // reading form input

            $.ajax({

                type :'POST',
                data : formData,
                url  : 'profile.php', 
                dataType : 'json',
                encode : true,
                success : function(response){

                    //response = JSON.parse(response);

                    if(response == "ok"){
                        $('#success').html('profile updated success');
                         setTimeout(' window.location.href = "profile.php"; ', 6000); // redirecting
                    }else{
                        //could not update

                        $('#error').html(response);

                    }
                },
                error : function(e){

                    console.log(e); // debugging puporse only
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's what you need on the frontend side.. Please note if you have more than one form in a single page then do not use `$('form').on('submit',function(event){});` you then give each form a unique `ID` then on replace the `form` on jquery/ajax with the iD of the form u wanna submit.

Then your server side.

> I have noticed that you have `header('location: profile.php');` that's
>   for redirecting, since we are sending ajax request to the server and
>   back to the client, you don't redirect on the server side, your
>   redirect using the client side after you have received the response
>   you expected from the server. I have commented that section where I do
>   redirecting with client side, on the script above.

**profile.php**

```
<?php

        $message = '';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        require 'connect.php';

        //validate your input field
        $newname = $_POST['changename'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['temp_user'];

        $sql = "UPDATE login SET login_name='$newname' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

           $message = 'ok'; // success
        }else{

            $message = 'system error could not update please try again later';
        }

        echo json_encode($message);//sending response back to the client

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

That's all you need, note you need to validate all your inputs fields in both the client and server side before using them.

I would also advice you to learn more about prepared statements, using mysqli or PDO they are very easy to use and very safe.

running a query like this : `$sql = "UPDATE login SET login_name='$newname' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";` is very unsafe, your inputs are not validated and not filtered and sanitized.

so with prepared statements its easy like :

**profile.php prepared**

```
 <?php

        $message = '';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        require 'connect.php';

        //validate your input field
        $newname = $_POST['changename'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['temp_user'];


        //prepare and bind
        $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE login SET login_name= ?  WHERE user_id= ? ");
        $sql->bind_param("si",$newname,$user_id);

        if($sql->execute()){

            $message = 'ok';
        }else{

            $message = 'Error Could not update please try again later';
        }

        echo json_encode($message);

        $conn->close();



    }
?>
```

> **`$sql->bind_param("si",$newname,$user_id);` This function binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the parameters.
>   are.By telling mysql what type of data to expect, we minimize the risk of SQL injections.**

Comment: Hi. Just a question. What should i include on "//response = JSON.parse(response);" ?

Comment: Just leave that as it is, that you use when your output comes with double quotations inside them

Comment: O okay. Another, should i change the response from here? if(response == "ok"), because it doesn't seem to be true for it is not redirecting after 6 seconds. Well, i did not change the $message = 'ok';

Comment: do u get any message on the page?

Comment: Yes. It says "ok" if the query is successful but still the success in ajax is not responding. So what i did is that i changed the $message to 'true' and used it in if on ajax. Another question, So in order for me to SHOW the new name i changed, it must be redirected. RIght? I mean it cant be changed unless i use window.location.href?

Comment: if its shows results like this **"ok"** then u need to uncomment this line : `//response = JSON.parse(response);`

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do in your form is to change your form method to POST (and not GET)  as you try to retrieve "changename" by POST method.
So change this:

```
<form action="profile.php" method="GET">
```

by this:

```
<form action="profile.php" method="POST">
```